# Best way to sql query a table based on a list of emails

Tags: mysql, sql, list, search

I have a list of emails who's records I need to pull. I'm sure I'm doing this the wrong way:

```
SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE` 
WHERE 
field_1 = 'something'
AND
created BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-30 23:59:59'
AND 
   email ="emaillist1@email.com"
OR email ="emaillist2@email.com"
OR email ="emaillist3@email.com"
```

this returned all the emails with the accounts but ignored field_1, so they were all different.
Is there a better way? The list of emails is over 100 long. Thanks.

Comment: How is the list of emails constructed? Where is it stored?  The best answer to hope for here is that it is already available in another table in the database.  Then you can JOIN the 2 tables if we know the structure of the other table.

Comment: I got a csv file with a list of emails. The table I'm looking it up on has the relevant data so I wouldn't need to join anything. Pretty much, here's a list of emails find value x where field_1 is something for these emails

Comment: What's with the down vote? Was it the question or how I asked it? Let me now how I can improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `MY_TABLE` 
WHERE field_1 = 'something' AND
      created BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-30 23:59:59' AND 
      email IN ('emaillist1@email.com', 'emaillist2@email.com', 'emaillist3@email.com');
```

You should use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: this seems to only bring up 9 results then it stops. When I look up the other ones individually they exist. `SELECT * FROM 'MY_TABLE' WHERE field_1 = 'something' AND created BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-30 23:59:59' AND email = "missingemail@email.com"`

Comment: @FelipeTadeo . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  The query should return all rows that match the conditions.

Comment: sorry I had an error in my code. This worked perfect! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket and try

```
 SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE` 
    WHERE 
    field_1 = 'something'
    AND
    created BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-30 23:59:59'
    AND 
       (email ="emaillist1@email.com"
    OR email ="emaillist2@email.com"
    OR email ="emaillist3@email.com")
```